# typescript TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript, decorator

My test code is like the following:

```
function test(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    return descriptor;
}

class Test {
    @test
    hello() {
    }
}
```

but the compiler give me error

```
Error:(33, 5) TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

I have already specified:

```
--experimentalDecorators --emitDecoratorMetadata
```

Comment: it works for me. which version of typescript are you compiling with?

Comment: tsc test.ts --experimentalDecorators --emitDecoratorMetadata

Comment: @iberbeu tsc --version Version 1.8.10

Comment: what about changing this `TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>` to this `PropertyDescriptor` and `target: Object` to `target: any`? It seems your declaration is not being recognized

Comment: @iberbeu I got the same error after changing the type

Comment: @Jeff where you able to resolve/work around this yet? I'm having the same problem

Comment: See new answer below (also with () => { } form and avoiding other compiler errors)

Answer (score 54):

Use `--target ES5 --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators`

or use the following config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5"
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, setting the target to `es2015` actually helped.

Comment: Thanks! For others: I was able to get this working (in a JS project) by using `"allowJs": true`. I didn't need to use `"target": "ES5"`

Comment: spent 3 hours trying to figure what happened......u have the solution

Answer (score 41):

It seems that TypeScript expects the return type of the decorator function to be 'any' or 'void'. So in the example below, if we add `: any` to the end, it ends up working.

```
function test(target: Object, 
              propertyKey: string, 
              descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): any {
    return descriptor;
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Setting traget ES5/es5/es2015 had no impact

Comment: Same here. None of the other suggestions worked. This is the only one.

Answer (score 32):

This cryptic error message seems to have had multiple root causes over time. As of end of 2019, here is what I could gather:

- **The message is misleading at best; the problem has nothing to do with ability to resolve signatures, or lack thereof.** Rather, it signals a typing problem on the decorators. For instance, the following code [signals TS1241 at `@f()`, but not at `@g()`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&target=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChEGIQIDOcANgKYB05cA5igESpoBcilAbgIbkg8olACZM0AbjyFEAJ0pQQMpKEiwEiFFB4z68gMLkeJEhx5gAngBpEABxlwblGVHMBpSuY4koMmGHrWwpQkEL42UHAyHAAq5o7CAAr2js7mACLBoTDhkQA86IgAvAB8iFxwMMLFGDj40oTEYGRUtAzMrBwQfFTCiADuMFAAFohMiADUiNr0IAC2lGBQJLQL9MMTo1M6cwtLYpJ1BAC+eCe4eCrQ8EiMNVINpBQ0dIxMtxzcfAJCohL3BHIFEpkOArupNNN5KYLNY7A4nC53J5EN5fP47od6o1ms82m90J1uiJ+oMRmNJtMdotllR-OtJmNKfNqft-ogzmc8BBDMZEHosGyAAKsIW3NnzYZwYQFTDs054IA):

```
function f() {
    console.log("f(): evaluated");
    return function (targetClass: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => void>) {
        console.log("f(): called with " + arguments.length + " arguments");
    }
}

function g() {
    console.log("g(): evaluated");
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        console.log("g(): called with " + arguments.length + " arguments");
    }
}

class C {
    @f()      // TypeScript signals TS1241 here
    @g()      // but not there
    method() { }
}
```

- **The calling convention on decorators**, and therefore their type, **depends on the targeted JavaScript dialect.** For instance, running the above code with `{"compilerOptions": { "target": "ES3" } }` results in

  ```
  f(): evaluated main-2.js line 1134 > eval:9:13
  g(): evaluated main-2.js line 1134 > eval:15:13
  g(): called with 2 arguments main-2.js line 1134 > eval:17:17
  f(): called with 2 arguments
  ```

  ( When [trying out the code on `typescriptlang.org/play`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&target=0&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChEGIQIDOcANgKYB05cA5igESpoBcilAbgIbkg8olACZM0AbjyFEAJ0pQQMpKEiwEiFFB4z68gMLkeJEhx5gAngBpEABxlwblGVHMBpSuY4koMmGHrWwpQkEL42UHAyHAAq5o7CAAr2js7mACLBoTDhkQA86IgAvAB8iFxwMMLFGDj40oTEYGRUtAzMrBwQfFTCiADuMFAAFohMiADUiNr0IAC2lGBQJLQL9MMTo1M6cwtLYpJ1BAC+eCe4eCrQ8EiMNVINpBQ0dIxMtxzcfAJCohL3BHIFEpkOArupNNN5KYLNY7A4nC53J5EN5fP47od6o1ms82m90J1uiJ+oMRmNJtMdotllR-OtJmNKfNqft-ogzmc8BBDMZEHosGyAAKsIW3NnzYZwYQFTDs054IA), first open the JavaScript console in your browser's Developer Tools; then click Run).
  On the other hand, [running the very same code under `"target": "ES5"`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&target=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChEGIQIDOcANgKYB05cA5igESpoBcilAbgIbkg8olACZM0AbjyFEAJ0pQQMpKEiwEiFFB4z68gMLkeJEhx5gAngBpEABxlwblGVHMBpSuY4koMmGHrWwpQkEL42UHAyHAAq5o7CAAr2js7mACLBoTDhkQA86IgAvAB8iFxwMMLFGDj40oTEYGRUtAzMrBwQfFTCiADuMFAAFohMiADUiNr0IAC2lGBQJLQL9MMTo1M6cwtLYpJ1BAC+eCe4eCrQ8EiMNVINpBQ0dIxMtxzcfAJCohL3BHIFEpkOArupNNN5KYLNY7A4nC53J5EN5fP47od6o1ms82m90J1uiJ+oMRmNJtMdotllR-OtJmNKfNqft-ogzmc8BBDMZEHosGyAAKsIW3NnzYZwYQFTDs054IA) results in

  ```
  f(): evaluated main-2.js line 1134 > eval:9:13
  g(): evaluated main-2.js line 1134 > eval:15:13
  g(): called with 3 arguments main-2.js line 1134 > eval:17:17
  f(): called with 3 arguments
  ```

  and accordingly, TypeScript is fully happy with `@f()` (and also `@g()`) in that case.

The simplest workaround is therefore **to pretend that the third parameter is optional,** i.e.

```
function f() {
    console.log("f(): evaluated");
    return function (targetClass: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => void>) {
        console.log("f(): called with " + arguments.length + " arguments");
    }
}

class C {
    @f()
    method() { }
}
```

which type-checks successfully under both [`"target": "ES3"`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&target=0&ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChEGIQIDOcANgKYB05cA5igESpoBcilAbgIbkg8olACZM0AbjyFEAJ0pQQMpKEiwEiFFB4z68gMLkeJEhx5gAngBpEABxlwblGVHMBpSuY4koMmGHrWwpQkEL42UHAyAPwcACrmjsIACvaOzuYAIsGhMOGRADzoiAC8AHyIXHAwwqUYOPjShMRgZFS0DMysHBB8VMKIAO4wUAAWiEyIANSI2vQgALaUYFAktEv0o1PjMzoLSytikg0EAL54Z7h4EIbGiHpYUoQAAqyPBIujcMJFmIgXF0A) and [`"target": "ES5"`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&target=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChEGIQIDOcANgKYB05cA5igESpoBcilAbgIbkg8olACZM0AbjyFEAJ0pQQMpKEiwEiFFB4z68gMLkeJEhx5gAngBpEABxlwblGVHMBpSuY4koMmGHrWwpQkEL42UHAyAPwcACrmjsIACvaOzuYAIsGhMOGRADzoiAC8AHyIXHAwwqUYOPjShMRgZFS0DMysHBB8VMKIAO4wUAAWiEyIANSI2vQgALaUYFAktEv0o1PjMzoLSytikg0EAL54Z7h4EIbGiHpYUoQAAqyPBIujcMJFmIgXF0A).

This “cheat” is especially important if using [angular-meteor](https://angular-meteor.com/), in which case you most definitely *do not* want to mess with the `"target"` setting in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: This answer saves me twice.

Answer (score 4):

Add this command in tsconfig for use decorator.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5"
  }
}
```

Decorator function should like this.

```
function(target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = async function(...args: any) {
      try {
        const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
      }
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you are using

> () => {}

function notation, switch to regular notation

> function() {}

Comment: Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: not sure, but could have to do with bindings, () => {} auto binds

Answer (score 2):

## This error comes from the typescript compile

To fix this error. you have to must add `tsconfig.json` to your project directory. and then if you want you can follow this `config` code.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": [
        "es5",
        "es6"
     ],
     "target": "es6",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "outDir": "./build",
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error reported in vsCode, but everything was ok at compile-time / runtime.
[image: error shown in vsCode]

I fixed it by checking the `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with tsyringe recently. I add @ts-ignore on the line before my decorator...

```
//@ts-ignore
public constructor(@inject(MongoClient) private client: MongoClient) {
```