# Type 'IDatabaseDriver<Connection>' does not satisfy the constraint 'AbstractSqlDriver<AbstractSqlConnection>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, mikro-orm

I am trying to use a context to define the type for the entity manage 'em' but the em type returns an error: type 'IDatabaseDriver' does not satisfy the constraint 'AbstractSqlDriver'.
Type 'IDatabaseDriver' is missing the following properties from type 'AbstractSqlDriver': connection, replicas, platform, mapJoinedProps, and 24 more.

**types.ts**

```
import { Connection } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { IDatabaseDriver } from "@mikro-orm/core/drivers/IDatabaseDriver";
import { EntityManager } from "@mikro-orm/postgresql";

export type MyContext = {
    em:  EntityManager<any> & EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>
}
```

**mikro-orm.config.ts**

```
import { __PROD__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core'
import {PostgreSqlDriver} from '@mikro-orm/postgresql'
import { User } from "./entities/User";
export default {
    migrations:{
        path: process.cwd() + '/src/migrations', // path to folder with migration files
        pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/, // how to match migration files
        disableForeignKeys: false
    },
    driver: PostgreSqlDriver,
    driverOptions: { connection: { timezone: '00:00' } },
    entities: [Post,User ],
    dbName:'altevibes',
    user:'logorcehab',
    password: 'login@Logout64',
    type:'postgresql',
    debug: !__PROD__
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

**index.ts**

```
import {MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core"
import 'reflect-metadata'
import {__PROD__} from "./constants"
//import { Post } from "./entities/Post"
import express from 'express'
import microConfig from './mikro-orm.config'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql'
import { PostsResolver } from "./resolvers/posts"
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/user"
const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig)
  await orm.getMigrator().up()
  
  const app= express()
  
  const apolloSever = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [PostsResolver, UserResolver],
      validate: false
    }),
    context: () => ({ em: orm.em })
  })
  apolloSever.applyMiddleware({ app })
  app.listen(8000,()=>{
      console.log('server on localhost 8000')
  })
}

console.log("Hello World")

main().catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

**posts.ts**

```
import { Resolver,Query, Ctx,Arg, Int, Mutation } from 'type-graphql'
import { Post } from '../entities/Post'
import { MyContext } from '../types'
@Resolver()
export class PostsResolver {
    @Query(()=>[Post])
    posts( @Ctx() {em}: MyContext ): Promise<Post[]> {
        return em.find(Post, {})
    }
    @Query(()=>Post,{nullable : true})
    post(
        @Arg('id', () => Int) id: number,  
        @Ctx() {em}: MyContext )
        : Promise<Post | null> {
        return em.findOne(Post, { id })
    }
    @Mutation(()=>Post)
    async createPost(
        @Arg('title', () => String) title: string,  
        @Ctx() {em}: MyContext )
        : Promise<Post> {
        const post = em.create(Post, {title})
        await em.persistAndFlush(post)
        return post
    }
    @Mutation(()=>Post,{ nullable: true})
    async updatePost(
        @Arg('id') id: number,
        @Arg('title',()=> String,{ nullable: true }) title: string, 
        @Ctx() {em}: MyContext )
        : Promise<Post | null> {
        const post = await em.findOne(Post, { id })
        if (!post) {
            return null
        }
        if (typeof title === 'undefined'){
            return null
        }
        post.title = title
        await em.persistAndFlush(post)        
        return post       
    }
    @Mutation(()=>Boolean)
    async deletePost(
        @Arg('id', () => Int) id: number,  
        @Ctx() {em}: MyContext )
        : Promise<Boolean> {
            try {
                await em.nativeDelete(Post, { id })
            } catch (error) {
                return false
            }
        return true
    }
}
```

**user.ts**

```
import { User } from '../entities/User'
import { Resolver, Ctx,Arg, Mutation, InputType, Field } from 'type-graphql'
import argon2 from 'argon2'
import { MyContext } from '../types'
@InputType()
class UsernamePasswordInput {
    @Field()
    username: string

    @Field()
    password: string
}

@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {
    @Mutation(()=> String)
    async register(
        @Arg("options") options: UsernamePasswordInput,
        @Ctx() { em }: MyContext
    ){
        const hashedPassword = argon2.hash(options.password)
        const user = em.create(User, { username: options.username, password: hashedPassword })
        await em.persistAndFlush(user)
        return user
    }
    
}
```

**Console Error**

```
src/resolvers/posts.ts:6:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

6     @Query(()=>[Post])
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:6:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<({ em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post[]>>'.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<({ em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post[]>>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(({ em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post[]>) | undefined'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '({ em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post[]>'.

6     @Query(()=>[Post])
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:10:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

10     @Query(()=>Post,{nullable : true})
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:10:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>>'.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '((id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>) | undefined'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>'.

10     @Query(()=>Post,{nullable : true})
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:17:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

17     @Mutation(()=>Post)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:17:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post>>'.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post>>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '((title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post>) | undefined'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post>'.

17     @Mutation(()=>Post)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:26:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

26     @Mutation(()=>Post,{ nullable: true})
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:26:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(id: number, title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>>'.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(id: number, title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '((id: number, title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>) | undefined'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(id: number, title: string, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Post | null>'.

26     @Mutation(()=>Post,{ nullable: true})
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:43:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

43     @Mutation(()=>Boolean)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/posts.ts:43:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Boolean>>'.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Boolean>>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '((id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Boolean>) | undefined'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(id: number, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<Boolean>'.

43     @Mutation(()=>Boolean)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/user.ts:16:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

16     @Mutation(()=> String)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/resolvers/user.ts:16:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(options: UsernamePasswordInput, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<User>>'.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(options: UsernamePasswordInput, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<User>>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '((options: UsernamePasswordInput, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<User>) | undefined'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(options: UsernamePasswordInput, { em }: MyContext) => Promise<User>'.

16     @Mutation(()=> String)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/types.ts:6:45 - error TS2344: Type 'IDatabaseDriver<Connection>' does not satisfy the constraint 'AbstractSqlDriver<AbstractSqlConnection>'.
  Type 'IDatabaseDriver<Connection>' is missing the following properties from type 'AbstractSqlDriver<AbstractSqlConnection>': connection, replicas, platform, mapJoinedProps, and 24 more.

6     em:  EntityManager<any> & EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Hey, It would be way easier to troubleshoot what's wrong, if there was a sample project somewhere on GitHub. :-)

Comment: I think this has to do with `tsconfig`. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456077/10240723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `EntityManager` expoted from driver package. That way it will be correctly typed to `SqlEntityManager<PostgreSqlDriver>`:

```
import { EntityManager } from "@mikro-orm/postgresql";

export type MyContext = {
    em:  EntityManager
}
```

And then when you initialze the ORM, you should specify the driver type:

```
const orm = await MikroORM.init<PostgreSqlDriver>(microConfig)
```

Then the `orm.em` is correctly typed the same way, so to `SqlEntityManager<PostgreSqlDriver>`.

Also instead of `Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0]` you can use just `Options` (exported from the core package).

Comment: still returns an error:  Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.